# Dump database and use it later after deleting migrations in django 1.11

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models

Sometimes I have to delete migrations for some reason and I will have to create new data again for django. How do I dump the `db` and use it later after I delete the migrations?

Comment: U want take whole db backup?

Comment: Que is not clear, Two things here Data(your application data), DataSchema(your database schema). Here do you want to dumb your database with your data or dumb your database schema alone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use the `dumpdata` command.

The following command will dump the whole database to a `db.json` file.

`./manage.py dumpdata > db.json`

After that, you can restore the data into db with `loaddata` command.

But, if you have made any critical change you might get the `IntegrityError`. 
To fix this issue you have to make sure to backup the database by excluding `contenttypes` and `auth.permissions` tables by running this command when dumping data:

`./manage.py dumpdata --exclude auth.permission --exclude contenttypes > db.json`

After that you can safely run `loaddata` command with a fresh database.

`./manage.py loaddata db.json`

Here you can find Django documentation on [dumpdata command](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/django-admin/#dumpdata).